# Trigger resize textareas by class name when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to trigger the `scrollHeight` of all textareas with a class of "abc" after .5 seconds after the window is resized.

This line doesn't seem to work. `document.getElementsByClassName(".abc").style.height = (document.getElementsByClassName(".abc")).scrollHeight+px';`

How can I trigger all textareas which have a class name of " abc" to fit its content height after the window is been resized?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});

$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
document.getElementsByClassName("abc").style.height = (document.getElementsByClassName("abc")).scrollHeight+'px';
});
```

Comment: Since you use jQuery => $(".abc").height( $(".abc")[0].scrollHeight )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    $(".abc").height( $(".abc")[0].scrollHeight );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery so use jQuery to set the heights

```
$(".abc").each(
    function() { 
        $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
    }
);
```

Now your code will fail because of multiple reasons. You can not set a value to an HTMLCollection. Your className has a `.` in it, it is not a selector.

So if you wanted to do it with plain old JavaScript

```
var tas = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
for(var i=0; i<tas.length; i++) {
    tas[i].style.height = tas[i].scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

Now in the end I do not think this is what you 100% want, but this is how to make your code above run.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".abc").css('height',document.getElementsByClassName(".abc").scrollHeight+'px');
```

Comment: DOM does not have a "css()" method